# Count distinct value acrross multiple columns

Tags: mysqli

I constructed table as follows :

```
SPKID     SPKDate    Engg1   Engg2   Engg3
————————————————————————————————————————————-
123.     2017-01-09       Amy.    Jhon.
```

Basically with the table above I want to record working allowance when engineer goes to the field. Each of the spk will consist of maximum 3 engineers. So, I have 3 columns for each engineer.

Now what I am trying to do is count how many times the engineer go each month.  And I need to count distinct through multiple columns.

The expected result:

John.    3

Amy.     2

Appreciate help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for SQL that would be able to accomplish this. If my understanding is wrong, this answer might not apply.

If this is a new table, I would consider normalizing it and splitting the engineers off into a separate, related table. If you did that you could pull the data relatively easily just using `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`. This would require code changes, and you would need to put some logic in place to limit the number of engineers to 3. You should be able to use a constraint (like a primary key) to prevent the same engineer from being added twice.

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx

The new table could simply have two fields:

```
SPKID
EngineerName
```

Then you could write something like this:

```
SELECT
    se.EngineerName,
    YEAR(s.SPKDate) AS SpkYear,
    MONTH(s.SPKDate) AS SpkMonth,
    COUNT(*) AS SpkTotal
FROM Spk AS s
    SpkEngineers AS se ON se.SPKID = s.SPKID
GROUP BY
    se.EngineerName,
    YEAR(s.SPKDate),
    MONTH(s.SPKDate)
ORDER BY
    se.EngineerName,
    YEAR(s.SPKDate),
    MONTH(s.SPKDate)
```

**Alternatively...**

If you are not able to re-structure the schema, you might be able to use something like this instead:

```
SELECT
    se.EngineerName,
    YEAR(s.SPKDate) AS SpkYear,
    MONTH(s.SPKDate) AS SpkMonth,
    COUNT(*) AS SpkTotal
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            SPKID,
            EngineerName
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    SPKID,
                    Engg1 AS EngineerName
                FROM Spk

                UNION ALL

                SELECT
                    SPKID,
                    Engg2 AS EngineerName
                FROM Spk

                UNION ALL

                SELECT
                    SPKID,
                    Engg3 AS EngineerName
                FROM Spk
            ) AS SpkEngineers
    ) AS se
    INNER JOIN Spk AS s ON s.SPKID = se.SPKID
WHERE
    se.EngineerName <> ''
    AND se.EngineerName IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    se.EngineerName,
    YEAR(s.SPKDate),
    MONTH(s.SPKDate)
ORDER BY
    se.EngineerName,
    YEAR(s.SPKDate),
    MONTH(s.SPKDate)
```

You would need to alter this to fit your actual schema.

Honestly, MySQL is not my strength, so there might be a more straight-forward way to do this. Just wanted to offer my thoughts.